# Is general anesthesia or coma considered sleep?

Tags: halacha, medicine, sleep

Is general anesthesia or coma considered Halachicly as sleep and in what aspects (like should one say Hamapil before or Birkas Hatorah after or wash hands etc)?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73688/9682

Comment: In terms of most halachot, I believe that it is. I think there's a rule that one who is unaware of his actions cannot be responsible for consequences. E.g. if a sleeping person spoke in his sleep and, say, agreed to marry a woman, I think the marriage is not valid. General, and sometimes local anesthesia causes sleep or drowsiness. I think medically-speaking a coma is considered a "long sleep".

Comment: I'm not convinced there is a Halakhic status of sleep fwiw. All the examples you've brought are subject to dispute

Comment: @DanF - that is not set in stone. For example, I believe someone who dreams about a neder, the neder is still considered to be in force and they would have to annul it.

Comment: @Dov https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%91

Comment: Thanks @DoubleAA