# Relation between brain damage and the soul

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, science, parts-of-the-body, soul

Physical damage to the brain can lead to various psychological and cognitive phenomena, like drastic changes in character, selective memory loss (like forgetting faces but remembering names or vice verse), losing learned motoric skills, speech impairments and more.

We say "נשמה שנתת בי", as G-d infuses the soul into us, and it seems that we don't have the ability to change it. But neuroscience says otherwise - by physical intervention to the brain serious changes to person's psycho (soul manifestations) can be made.

How does Judaism view the relation between brain damage and changes to the soul? How can it possibly be connected?

Comment: Subset of this question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27305/